# Is it possible to do helm-org-in-buffer-heading with matching of inherited tags?

Tags: org-mode

I like being able to filter by tag and I like to use helm-org-in-buffer-heading [helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm)/ worf-goto [worf](https://github.com/abo-abo/worf).

Is it possible to combine them?

I.e, with Worf-goto I can search headings and their tags, but it doesn't list headings that should inherit the tag. e.g

```
* Emacs tasks :emacs:
** Figure out ultimate macro that will do my work for me
** Make emacs make my coffee in the morning
```

If I search for ':emacs ultimate', ideally it should match the 1st sub-item, but worf-goto/helm-heading search doesn't. It can either find the line with :emacs: or the line with 'ultimate', it can't match them both.

The agenda view C-c s kinda works. I can first do a search and then narrow down via tags. But this is a 2 step process and it only works on agenda files. I have a lot of non-agenda org files that I'd like to parse with heading/tag combo.

Thoughts?

**[EDIT]**
At the moment I'm tagging every headings with all the tags (e.g below) and I'm looking forward to the day where I can make use of the inheritance instead.

```
* Emacs tasks :emacs:
** Figure out ultimate macro that will do my work for me  :emacs:
** Make emacs make my coffee in the morning  :emacs:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after a while.

```
C-c a  (agenda)
m   (match tags)
(helm-swoop)
```

With this combo I first search headlines by tag, and then I can narrow things down further with helm.

The only thing is that I need to have all the files I want to search as Agenda files.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very rough sketch. The idea is to collect all tags with `org-get-tags`, which also collects inherited tags, and add them to candidate in place of the old tags.

```el
(cl-defmethod helm-setup-user-source ((source helm-org-headings-class))
  (setf (slot-value source 'candidate-transformer)
        '((lambda (candidates)
            (helm-org-get-candidates candidates))
          (lambda (candidates)
            (cl-loop
             for i in candidates
             for len = (string-width (car i))
             for hl = (when (string-match
                             "^\\(\\**\\)\\(\\* \\)\\(.[^:\n\]*\\)\\(:.+:\\)?" (car i))
                        (replace-match "\\1\\2\\3" t nil (car i)))
             for col = (if (> org-tags-column 0)
                       org-tags-column (- org-tags-column))
             for trunc = (if (> len col)
                             (helm-substring hl col)
                           hl)
             for sep = (make-string (- col (length trunc))
                                    ?\s)
             for tags = (with-helm-current-buffer
                          (let ((tag (org-get-tags (goto-char (cdr i)))))
                            (if tag (concat ":" (mapconcat #'identity tag ":") ":")
                  "")))
             collect (cons (concat trunc sep tags)
                           (cdr i))))))
  (setf (slot-value source 'filtered-candidate-transformer)
    '(helm-fuzzy-highlight-matches)))
```